# How can I get absolute value of Q register (int64x2_t) with arm v7 neon intrinsic?

Tags: arm, neon

for example:

```cpp
int64x2_t a{1,-1};
auto abs_val = vabsq_s64(a);//But this intrinsic is only or A64 architecture.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing a lot of 64-bit operations you should really think twice about your hardware; there are a lot of functions where the 64-bit versions are missing on ARMv7, so if you can upgrade to AArch64 you really should.  Assuming you don't have that option…

Basically, what `vabsq_s64` does is something like this for each lane:

```c
res[i] = a[i] < 0 ? -a[i] : a[i];
```

You just need to use other intrinsics to do that.

Let's take care of the negation first.  NEON has a [`vnegq_s64`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics?search=vnegq_s64) function which would do the trick, but it's AArch64-only.  However, we can just subtract a from 0 instead: `vsubq_s64(vdupq_n_s64(0), a)`.

Now we have to choose between the negated value and the original value, which is the domain of [`vbslq_s64`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics?search=vbslq_s64).  The first argument to `vbslq_s64` is a mask used to determine which of the other arguments to get the value of for each bit.  Basically, `vbslq_s64(a, b, c)` is logically like `(a & b) | (~a & c)`.

In order to use `vbslq_s64` we first need a mask with all zeros in a lane when we want to use one value, and all ones when we want to use the other.  If you were on AArch64 I'd say to use [`vcltzq_s64`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics?search=vcltzq_s64), but we're not.  Even [`vcltq_s64()`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics?search=vcltq_s64) is AArch64-only, but that's okay since there is a better way anyways… just use a right arithmetic shift, which will shift in sign bits (1 for negatives, 0 for positives).  You want the sign bit to be broadcast to every bit in each lane, so for a 64-bit value that would be `vshrq_n_s64(a, 63)`.

Of course `vbslq_s64` takes a `uint64x2_t` for the first parameter but what you have is an `int64x2_t`, so you'll need to use [`vreinterpretq_u64_s64`](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics?search=vreinterpretq_u64_s64) to convert.

Putting it all together:

```c
int64x2_t my_vabsq_s64(int64x2_t a) {
  return vbslq_s64(
      vreinterpretq_u64_s64(vshrq_n_s64(a, 63)),
      vsubq_s64(vdupq_n_s64(0), a),
      a);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing!!! Thank you, sir. I can twice about the device to AARCH64, but it needs to be compatible with old armv7 android devices. I use macro `__aarch64__` to decide which version of code should be used.